# How to get current directory in wolframscript (without frontend, i.e. not using NotebookDirectory)

Tags: files-and-directories

I want to get the current working directory, or the directory/path where the script being called when using wolframscript. Without frontend, i.e. not using NotebookDirectory.

Because when I want to get the current directory by NotebookDirectory in wolframscript, it shows:

> FrontEndObject::notavail:    A front end is not available; certain
>   operations require a front end.

### Updated

With the help of @Edmund, I use `Directory` to solve this problem.

But it introduced another problem. If I use `Directory` in package files, the notebook cannot use the package, because `Directory` returns home path. But if I use `NotebookDirectory`, the wolframscript cannot use the package, because `NotebookDirectory` uses frontend. How can I solve this?

### Updated

With the help of @MB1965
`If[$InputFileName="", NotebookDirectory[], Directory[]]` will solve the above problem.

Further, If I use

```
ppNoteBookDir = If[$BatchInput, Directory[], NotebookDirectory[]];
Needs["msgCommon`", FileNameJoin[{ppNoteBookDir, "msg_common.wl"}]]
```

Then the first time I evaluate the notebook, it shows:
[image]

It need evaluate the notebook a second time to work right. Why and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @cmal I marked this topic a duplicate, let me know if you disagree, I'm open to discussion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55328/discussion-on-question-by-cmal-how-to-get-current-directory-in-wolframscript-wi).